# how to validate value from input field through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have two text field on which when I take my mouse,then calender along with text to enter time appears in both the textfield. First textfield should be less than another textfield.For this I used javascript but its not working.My code for this is:-

```
<form method="post" action="Compvac8.jsp">
Select Reference:
<select name="ref_logtime" >
<option value="Select">Select</option>
<c:forEach var="aff" items="${obj.connect()}">
<option value="${aff.value}">${aff.key} ${aff.value}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>

<br><br>
<b>Select Date to be compared</b><br>
<p>Date: <input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker"></p>

<input id="startdate" type="text" size="25" name="startdate" onclick="javascript:NewCal('startdate','ddmmmyyyy',true,24)" >
<a>
<img src="images/cal.gif" width="10" height="10" border="0" alt="Pick a date">
</a>

<input id="enddate" type="text" size="25" name="enddate" onclick="javascript:NewCal('enddate','ddmmmyyyy',true,24)" >
<a>
<img src="images/cal.gif" width="10" height="10" border="0" alt="Pick a date">
</a>

 <input type="submit"  onclick="date_comapare()" value="Submit"><br>

</form>
```

Javascript code is-

```
  function date_comapare()
{

   var d1=document.getElementById("startdate").value; // start date
   var d2=document.getElementById("enddate").value; //end date
   //if (new Date(d2).valueOf() < new Date(d1).valueOf()) 
       alert(d1);
   alert(d2);
   if(new Date(d2).getTime() < new Date(d1).getTime())

   {
      alert("Endate date should be greater than start date");  // handle  your error validation here
      return false;
   }return true;
}
</script>
```

I even also tried folowing in javascript-

```
if(d2 < d1)
   {
      alert("Endate date should be greater than start date"); 
      return false;
   }
```

I want my startdate to be lesser than enddate.How to do that.I can use server side validation also.

Comment: dear @tiddi rastogi, plz change `getElementIdBy` in your code to `getElementById`

Answer (score 2):

Wrong function on Document, needs to be:

```
   var d1=document.getElementById("startdate").value; // start date
   var d2=document.getElementById("enddate").value; //end date
```

You're passing strings instead of variables.

```
if(new Date(d2).valueOf() < new Date(d1).valueOf())
```

Please make sure the values you're initializing Date with are valid constructor arguments. MDN has a great page [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: I tried but ,when I click submit and enddate is smaller than startdate then no error or alert message is shown.

Comment: can't I directly use d2 instead of new Date(d2)

Comment: This really depends on the value of "d2". Please refer to the page I linked.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems, it should be `getElementById` not `getElementIdBy` then `d1` and `d2` are variables not string literals

```
function date_comapare() {

    var d1 = document.getElementById("startdate").value; // start date
    var d2 = document.getElementById("enddate").value; //end date

    if (new Date(d2) < new Date(d1)) {
        alert("Endate date should be greater than start date"); // handle  your error validation here
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I tried but ,when I click submit and enddate is smaller than startdate then no error or alert message is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return true in date_compare function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function date_comapare()
{

   var d1=document.getElementById("startdate").value; // start date
   var d2=document.getElementById("enddate").value; //end date

   if(new Date('d2').valueOf() < new Date('d1').valueOf())
   {
      alert("Endate date should be greater than start date");  // handle      your error validation here
      return false;
   }

   return true; // <------ here, you should return true.

}
```

Comment: why did you use single quotes inside Date() function like Date('d2') ??

Comment: I tried but ,when I click submit and enddate is smaller than startdate then no error or alert message is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `date.getTime` Method

```
if (new Date(d2).getTime()  <  new Date(d1).getTime()) {}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72558/discussion-on-answer-by-med-amine-touil-how-to-validate-value-from-input-field-t).

Comment: @tiddirastogi is it the date picker is working perfectly ?? i mean when you click on the textbox then a calender will appear and there you can select your date ?? is it came like that ???

Comment: try with button type="button" and come to chat in the above comment lin

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV,it shows the alert message of if ,but when I click on ok of message box,it is being redirected to next page.

Answer (score 0):

Well,I don't know what's the use of `NewCal`,If that makes a well formatted Date try this:

```
new Date(d2).valueOf() < new Date(d1).valueOf()
```

Date accept a time value as parameter that may be a number or like '2010/2/1' or 'December 17, 1995' etc.In your case,try to validate it  like `console.log(new Date(d1))`.

To use console.log(),You have to make firebug installed in your firefox.Without that you can use alert.Put it in your function right after d1 is assigned.
like `var d1=...;alert(new Date(d1))` .
@Arunprasanth KV '9-10-2015' is not a valid Date() parameter.

Comment: what does this console.log() owrkand how to use it to validate .?

Comment: What does console.log()do and how to use uit to compare values of both the input fields?

Comment: i had update fiddle with valid date time thanks for corrections